# Netlogo profiler extension : exclusive time greater than inclusive time

Tags: netlogo, profiler

Recently, I have started using netlogo profiler to optimize my code.
On generating the report, I could see that for one of the procedures, exclusive time reported was greater than the inclusive time. I assume exclusive time should always be less than or equal to the inclusive time. Are there any cases when exclusive time can be greater than the inclusive time ?

**UPDATE :**
Apologies for not posting the profiler dump earlier itself. I tried to find the reason for this by splitting the procedure with greater exclusive time into smaller procedures to narrow down the code which might be causing this error. Please find below the profiler dump for the changed code. You can see that the exclusive time for HATCH_ROSETTES procedure is greater than the inclusive time. I believe there is some error related to the **hatch** procedure because the HATCH_ROSETTES is a one statement procedure which just calls **hatch**

```
End of simulation run.
BEGIN PROFILING DUMP
Sorted by Exclusive Time
Name                               Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls
FIND_NEIGHBOR                    2796258 270525.771 270525.771      0.097
FIND_AND_CALC_OVERLAP            2796258 297711.971  24470.228      0.009
GROW_ROSETTES                    2796258 305232.636   7089.417      0.003
SEEDLING_ESTABLISHMENT              2240   4918.394   5206.214      2.324
GO                                    60 258415.932   2894.939     48.249
CALC_OVERLAP                     2927018   2765.982   2765.982      0.001
UPDATEPLOT                            60    710.640    710.640     11.844
HATCH_ROSETTES                    124755      8.978    431.248      0.003
GROW_SEEDLINGS                    208344    200.899    200.899      0.001
UPDATEHISTOGRAM                        2    195.879    195.879     97.939
SEED_DISPERSAL                       280      3.319      3.319      0.012
HERBICIDE_CONCENTRATION                6      2.028      2.028      0.338

Sorted by Inclusive Time
GROW_ROSETTES                    2796258 305232.636   7089.417      0.003
FIND_AND_CALC_OVERLAP            2796258 297711.971  24470.228      0.009
FIND_NEIGHBOR                    2796258 270525.771 270525.771      0.097
GO                                    60 258415.932   2894.939     48.249
SEEDLING_ESTABLISHMENT              2240   4918.394   5206.214      2.324
CALC_OVERLAP                     2927018   2765.982   2765.982      0.001
UPDATEPLOT                            60    710.640    710.640     11.844
GROW_SEEDLINGS                    208344    200.899    200.899      0.001
UPDATEHISTOGRAM                        2    195.879    195.879     97.939
HATCH_ROSETTES                    124755      8.978    431.248      0.003
SEED_DISPERSAL                       280      3.319      3.319      0.012
HERBICIDE_CONCENTRATION                6      2.028      2.028      0.338

Sorted by Number of Calls
CALC_OVERLAP                     2927018   2765.982   2765.982      0.001
GROW_ROSETTES                    2796258 305232.636   7089.417      0.003
FIND_AND_CALC_OVERLAP            2796258 297711.971  24470.228      0.009
FIND_NEIGHBOR                    2796258 270525.771 270525.771      0.097
GROW_SEEDLINGS                    208344    200.899    200.899      0.001
HATCH_ROSETTES                    124755      8.978    431.248      0.003
SEEDLING_ESTABLISHMENT              2240   4918.394   5206.214      2.324
SEED_DISPERSAL                       280      3.319      3.319      0.012
GO                                    60 258415.932   2894.939     48.249
UPDATEPLOT                            60    710.640    710.640     11.844
HERBICIDE_CONCENTRATION                6      2.028      2.028      0.338
UPDATEHISTOGRAM                        2    195.879    195.879     97.939
END PROFILING DUMP
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the profiler results themselves?

Comment: Fallible people write profilers, so there are bugs.